# I'm getting data as Form Data instead of JSON in remote pagination

Tags: json, tabulator

**I am using Tabulator remote pagination with following config**

```
table = new Tabulator("#data-table", {height : "800px",
                                            pagination : "remote",
                                            overflow:"auto",
                                            layout : "fitData",
                                            paginationButtonCount : 6,
                                            ajaxFiltering:true,
                                            headerFilterPlaceholder:"",
                                            ajaxSorting:true,
                                            placeholder : "No Records Found. Click on 'Clear All Filters' button to clear the filters if any",
                                            keybindings:false,
                                            ajaxURL: "findDataSet", 
                                             ajaxConfig:{
                                                 method:"POST", 
                                             },
                                            ajaxContentType:"JSON",
                                            columns : columsData,
                                            ajaxParams:{waveId:waveId,primaryClecName : primaryClecName,status:status,noOfCircuits:noOfCircuits},
                                            paginationDataReceived:{
                                                "last_page":"maxNumberOfPage", 
                                                "data":"ntportalFields", } 
});
```

**I am expecting request payload (JSON format) in the java service. But I'm getting form data as below.**

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9ajA2zFVTs7hpxzL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="waveId"

11833
------WebKitFormBoundary9ajA2zFVTs7hpxzL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="primaryClecName"

ACCESS%20POINT%20INC
------WebKitFormBoundary9ajA2zFVTs7hpxzL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status"

Migration%20Complete
------WebKitFormBoundary9ajA2zFVTs7hpxzL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="noOfCircuits"

5
------WebKitFormBoundary9ajA2zFVTs7hpxzL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="page"

1
------WebKitFormBoundary9ajA2zFVTs7hpxzL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="size"
```

**How can I get it as JSON format?
Thanks in advance :)**

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is because you have capitalized the value you have passed into the ***ajaxContentType*** property

```
ajaxContentType:"JSON",
```

Should be:

```
ajaxContentType:"json",
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the lower case too. It is not working. I'm still getting it as form data.

Comment: which version of Tabulator are you using

Comment: I used Version 4.0.5